# Adding new dependencies to yeoman angular-fullstack project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I have started working on a new project in node js and I have generated the project using yeoman's angular fullstack generator. And now I would like to add a new bower dependency and a new node dependency. What is the best way to do this? Should I simply add the dependency in bower.json and package.json or should I run a specific command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need yeoman to install those dependancies for you.  Instead, yeoman gives you an environment with everything set up to use tihngs like bower, npm, grunt etc.  You can add additional dependencies like you normally would using npm or bower.

for bower (http://bower.io/) -

```
bower install -S <name-of-your-dependancy>
```

that command downloads the code for you, and it also adds a reference to it in your bower.json

similar for node (https://www.npmjs.com/) -

```
npm install -S <name-of-your-dependancy>
```

Comment: My new npm dependency needs a "require()". What is the file where I have to make the export ?

Comment: Exactly where do I include that dependency and how do I inject it into app. Let's say I wanna use angular-bootstrap-ui. It's not clearly mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

use npm packet manager, to install components, like if you want to install cordova, use:

npm install -g cordova

For installing AngularJs, follow the official site guide lines:
https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started